# Hiding heroku URL when forwarding from GoDaddy (without using masking)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, heroku, environment-variables, forwarding

I am currently forwarding to a heroku app from my GoDaddy domain, and it works, although users still see my heroku url in the browser once landing on the site. I previously tried using "forwarding with masking" on GoDaddy, but that broke everything, and is a well-documented "don't" when forwarding from GoDaddy.

Currently, my A record is:
[image]

and my CNAMEs are:

[image]

Does anyone know how to hide the heroku URL in the browser WITHOUT reverting to forward with masking? Do I need to change my application host variable somewhere in my app?

Answer (score 0):

It's a DNS issue and can be resolved without any changes on Heroku. GoDaddy doesn't support root CNAME flattening, so you'll have to have someone else "manage" your DNS. You can keep your domain at GoDaddy, but create an account somewhere else that supports CNAME flattening, like CloudFlare. YOu can get a free web account, and just configure your GoDaddy account to use the new `Nameservers` CloudFlare (or some other provider) provides you.

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain